# Can the favicons be bigger in the user profile pages?

Tags: bug, design

At the top of the browser window, the favicons fill up the normal amount of space. But when I look at my profile on any SE site, the C.SE favicon appears smaller, and part of the design is nearly invisible.

[image]

(It looks about half the size of the similarly-shaped Sci-Fi and Math SE Favicons. Is there anything that can be done about this?

Comment: the file dimensions are the same for all favicons, but I can see why the Christianity appears smaller due to the outer ring is in a lighter color. I'll make some adjustments.